# Converting IQy files to XLSX using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I currently wrote a Pyhon script that extract metadata from SharePoint online using the "Export to Excel" button. When the data saves it saves as a IQy files (internet query file) and I need to save it as an XLSX. Theres about 30 files that I want to loop through and save.

These IQy files can be opened with excel and then I can use saveas to save it as an XLSX. Is there a way to automate this? I found some code in another forum but I don't completely understand it.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yyyy") & " " & "Position Report Ver.2.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

the line I don't understand is `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yyyy") & " " & "Position Report Ver.2.xlsx", FileFormat:=51`

Would it be possible to get an explanation of this line? or is there another way to use the saveas to convert these files into XLSX? I'm open to using any other language as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty clear. It's calling [`SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) to save the workbook to a particular path, using the `FileFormat` argument to save it as an XLSX file, [which is type 51](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat).

Comment: ok maybe I wasn't clear, the part that I don't understand is the `"\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yyyy) & " " & "Position Report Ver.2.xlsx"` is the backslash followed by the format being added the full name of the file?

Comment: It's simple string concatenation to build a filename with the date in it.